# Google Cloud bitnami wordpress installation permissions

Tags: bitnami, gcloud

I have setup an installation of Bitnami Wordpress Multisite in google cloud. I have also setup the SSH, and I am able to connect through SSH, but I want to go to the wordpress installation and edit files / upload plugins / edit permissions. Any idea of how I am able to do that. I followed bitnami's guide but it still does not allow me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloud image of Bitnami WordPress Multisite is already configured with the right permissions to allow you install or upload plugins, edit any file, etc using the WordPress administration panel.

However, if you are using an old version of WordPress you may find some permissions problems. If it is your case, you can try the following workaround:

- Open `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php`
- Look for `define('FS_METHOD', 'ftptext');`
- Replace it with `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`
- Change the permissions of `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs` to allow the server user (`daemon`) to make the modifications. You can do that by executing `sudo chown -R daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`
- Go to the WordPress admin panel and check you can perform the operation you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> For security reasons, WordPress files are not editable from the
>   WordPress application itself. We would suggest using an FTP client to
>   edit the files remotely.
>
> Another option is to change the permissions to be able to edit from
>   the WordPress application temporarily. Note that this configuration is
>   not secure so please revert it after editing the files temporarily:

```
sudo chown daemon:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/
```

- Afterwards revert the changes to stay secure..

For /wp-content folder

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content
```

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/wordpress/